# MacBook Pro 2010 with external monitor Eizo 2560x1600

Tags: macbook, display, resolution, macbook-pro

I just purchased an Eizo 30" multiscan 2560x1600 to use on my MacBook Pro 2010, and I also purchased from MonoPrice the mini displayport + USB to dual link DVI adapter, I read many stories on the original from Apple, but it does not work properly.

The MacBook Pro recognize the monitor and its resolution of 2560x1600 and when I select this resolution the monitor displays a poor image, like blurred and letter rendering are horrible, I need to go back to Apple resolution 1920x1200.
Could you assist?

Comment: Apologies to all, but it was an operator mistake, let me explain:
Eizo monitor FlexScan SX3031W-H offers single and dual display connection, this last one allows you to connect two computers to the same display with 1280x1600 resolution for each computer. Eizo supplies two signal cables, one for single display and the other for the dual display operation and I used the wrong cable, shame on me.
Thank you for your assistance.

With Regards,