# Dual DVI-D cable shows 2560x1600 monitor resolution only partially

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, dvi, cable

Recently installed a new quality monitor capable of a screen **resolution of 2560x1600** that replaced my old 1920x1200 monitor. The old Dual DVI-D cable was able to feed the old monitor perfectly with 1920x1200 @60Hz with 32 bit colors per pixel.

When however the new monitor now is connected at its own native resolution of 2560x1600 (or even 1920x1200) through the same Dual DVI-D cable of 1.8 meters, then **all kinds of artifacts show up** (see picture).

When however the refreshrate now is brought **down to just 37 Hz**, then the picture becomes perfectly sharp, without a single (sub)pixel defect. But I would like to have that sharp native resolution at 60Hz not 37 Hz. How to achieve that? is the monitor faulty or the cable?

[image: 30" monitor running at 2560x1600@50Hz]

And how is it possible that the same cable *could* feed the previous monitor with 1920x1200 perfectly, but not the new monitor with the same 1920x1200 resoluion without the image becoming artifacted?

Comment: We need way more info to give you a real answer...  Exactly what make and model of monitor is it? Exactly which make/model of video adapter/card are you using?  Does the monitor actually support the 2560x1600 resolution at something higher than 37Hz?  I do agree though that it does sound like you may be running into the single-link limit; so are you *SURE* that both your DVI cable and video card's DVI port are both dual-link capable?  Have you tried a different cable?  how about trying the monitor on another computer?

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for your comment here are the EXACT answers:  EIZO SX3031W 30" (new)  and EIZO S2410W 24" (old) both having two DVI-D input connections, graphics card: Gigabyte Nvidia 470 GTX 2GB ram dual DVI-D outputs. Apparently it does support that @37Hz! is that strange?? Curious!! Before taking the plunge to purchase another cable (or pc) need to first find out whats wrong here before purchasing HighQ stuff :)  Thanks for any ideas/suggestions/logics.

Comment: Educated guess without being familiar with these monitors, but this sounds like the cable to me.

Comment: I think you just don't have a real dual-link DVI cable.  Check out this similar/related question about the same monitor with the same problems: [MacBook Pro 2010 with external monitor Eizo 2560x1600](http://superuser.com/questions/265743/macbook-pro-2010-with-external-monitor-eizo-2560x1600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your cable make sure it is indeed a dual link cable. here's a reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Dual-link_DVI

The only DVI cable that will hit the resolution you want is  DVI-D Dual link

Comment: Thanks @acme64  i've checked the cable and it is an Dual Link DVI-D cable  strange huh?!

Comment: @Sam May be the second link is defect. Your old monitor did not made use of the second link.